# How to recover deleted all files in git

Tags: git

how to recover all deleted files in git ,it has deleted all my MacBook files how to recover it

Comment: You have to provide more details on what happened. Please read up on [how to ask a good question here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have deleted your local repository also. Now you can only recover (using git) if you have a backup of your local repository on another machine. For example, you may have pushed your repository in a remote repository (e.g. GitHub, Bitbucket, GitLab etc.) In this case just go to your repository get the url (as you are beginer use http(s) url). And clone in your MacBook.

But if you have your local repository, just run

```
git reset --hard
```

in your repository, it will remove all the local changes.

Answer (score 1):

Re-clone the repository from where ever its being hosted (ie github.com)